# Partial data from Facebook graph API event search

Tags: facebook, http, facebook-graph-api, pagination

Im tried using facebook graph search API to get a list of all events with search string "Party". The graph explorer returns only a portion of the results that shows up when i use the search bar in www.facebook.com and type "Party".

```
graph explorer: https://graph.facebook.com/search?access_token=<YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN>&q=Party&type=event&limit=100&offset=0
```

Can someone tell me what im missing here? I do not know what the search bar in FB is doing internally & would appreciate if someone can tell me if my query is incomplete or missing something. Thanks.

Comment: Does pagination return more results?

Comment: @asarva - Not sure what you mean, if you are asking if union of all pages contains complete data? then No. Its only partial compared to what you would get when you search for the same string in facebook search bar.